# How can I launch an instance of an application using Python?

Tags: python, scripting, ipc

I am creating a Python script where it does a bunch of tasks and one of those tasks is to launch and open an instance of Excel. What is the ideal way of accomplishing that in my script?

Comment: ipc - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While the `Popen` answers are reasonable for the general case, I would recommend `win32api` for this specific case, if you want to do something useful with it:

It goes something like this:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Documents and Settings\\GradeBook.xls')
xl.Visible = True    # optional: if you want to see the spreadsheet
```

Taken from [a mailing list post](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-June/315330.html) but there are plenty of examples around.

Comment: If you want to see the excel spreadsheet as well, then you need to add xl.Visible = True

Answer (score 8):

or

```
os.system("start excel.exe <path/to/file>")
```

(presuming it's in the path, and you're on windows)

and also on Windows, just `start <filename>` works, too - if it's an associated extension already (as xls would be)

Comment: Note that on Windows you will see the cmd window quickly open and close if you `os.system()`. IMHO it's better to use `os.startfile()`.

Answer (score 7):

I like `popen2` for the ability to monitor the process.

```
excelProcess = popen2.Popen4("start excel %s" % (excelFile))
status = excelProcess.wait()
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/popen2.html

**EDIT**: be aware that calling `wait()` will block until the process returns.  Depending on your script, this may not be your desired behavior.

Answer (score 7):

The **subprocess** module intends to replace several other, older modules and functions, such as:

- os.system
- os.spawn*
- os.popen*
- popen2.*
- commands.*

.

```
import subprocess

process_one = subprocess.Popen(['gqview', '/home/toto/my_images'])

print process_one.pid
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, I would suggest os.system. In case anyone is looking for a Mac-compatible solution, here is an example:

```
import os
os.system("open /Applications/Safari.app")
```

Answer (score 0):

os.system("open file.xls")

Comment: Probably works on NeXTstep too. But certainly not Windows or UNIX.  Given that the question asks about Excel, I'd assume OS X or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I like `os.startfile("path to file")` as it opens the file as if you've double clicked to open.

I found that with `os.system("start excel filename")` it opened it like a file opened from the web and you had to enable editing.