# Python Xlrd read excel file error

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have been working on a script on Windows and now when changing the platform to Linux/Ubuntu I am having some issues. In the example below I am just trying to print the sheetnames but receicing some errors which I have never seen before. May this be a issue with Xlrd ? Because I am able to open the Excel file in Libreoffice.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import xlrd

xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/usage01.12.2015_31.12.2015.xls')

sheet_names = xl_workbook.sheet_names()
print('Sheet Names', sheet_names)
```

Error:

```
    0  5 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
   20  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
   40= 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
   60  4 4 3 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./forbruk.py", line 4, in <module>
    xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('/home/ubuntu/Downloads/usage01.12.2015_31.12.2015.xls')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/xlrd/__init__.py", line 441, in open_workbook
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/xlrd/book.py", line 87, in open_workbook_xls
    ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/xlrd/book.py", line 592, in biff2_8_load
    cd.locate_named_stream(UNICODE_LITERAL(qname))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 390, in locate_named_stream
    d.tot_size, qname, d.DID+6)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xlrd-0.9.4-py2.7.egg/xlrd/compdoc.py", line 418, in _locate_stream
    raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s]))
xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: Workbook corruption: seen[2] == 4
```

Comment: Maybe try using a different name like `snames` because `sheet_names` is a method of the reading class.

Comment: Could you trying printing the `sheet names by index`, `print sheet_names.sheet_by_index(0)` but I think the problem is with your excel file.

Comment: I receive the errors only by having the line 'xl_workbook = xlrd.open_workbook'. I am pretty confused, since I can open the excel file in LibreOffice without any problems.

Comment: Looks like a corrupt set of files, contact the producers and get them to fix.

Comment: Or you can comment the line which is raising the error. It will definitely solve your problem!

Comment: reading with olefile worked for me, as described here http://www.crimulus.com/2013/09/19/reading-compound-file-binary-format-files-generated-by-phpexcel-with-pythondjango-xlrd/

Answer (score 1):

If you need data from a remote service, it's a hack, but commenting out line 418 `(raise CompDocError("%s corruption: seen[%d] == %d" % (qname, s, self.seen[s])))` in compdoc.py seems to work okay.

Also look into this documentation [source](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/issues/66)

Comment: That didn't woork. The funny thing is that I can read the excel file in Windows with but not in Ubuntu with Xlrd. There isn't any bug with the file it seems like.

Comment: I am outisde right now, can you send me your file? Upload somewhere and give me the link?