# python is generating MSAT Extension error while reading the excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Python is generating this error by reading the excel file by all the method i.e pandas, openpyxl.

raise CompDocError(msg)
xlrd.compdoc.CompDocError: MSAT extension: accessing sector 131072 but only 22863 in file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60416081/9110912) answer:

```
#!pip install OleFileIO-PL
import OleFileIO_PL
import pandas as pd

path = 'file.xls'
with open(path,'rb') as file:
    ole = OleFileIO_PL.OleFileIO(file)
    if ole.exists('Workbook'):
        d = ole.openstream('Workbook')
        x=pd.read_excel(d,engine='xlrd')
        print(x.head())
```