# How to call a *.jsl script from python script

Tags: python-3.x, sas-jmp, jsl

I have a python script running. I want to call *.jsl script in my running python script and want to make use of it's output in python. May I know how can I do that?

Comment: What's a jmp script? (The tag you're using seems to apply entirely to the ASM instruction...) (And whatever it is, you probably want to look at the subprocess module).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should take a look at the [JMP automation guide](http://www.jmp.com/support/downloads/pdf/jmp1001/automation_reference.pdf).

You can automate JMP from Python using the `win32com` interface, which is unfortunately quite buggy and incomplete. I've written a custom library of code to work around these issues, largely because my job requires me to work with JMP extensively and its built-in [jsl](/questions/tagged/jsl) programming language is awful at many things.

Comment: FYI: the link to the JMP automation guide is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jmp.exe is available in your system environment so that if you type "jmp.exe" in the command line, it would launch jmp. Then have your *.jsl ready.
use python procees to run this command "jmp.exe *.jsl" and that would open jmp and run the *.jsl script and then you can import whatever you generate from jmp back in to python.

Answer (score -1):

I'm on a Mac, and this works

```
import os
os.system('open /Applications/JMP\ Pro\ 13.app/Contents/MacOS/JMP /path/filename.jsl')
```

there is a space between the path/executable and the path/name.

In your JSL make sure the first line only has  `//!`
This will make the script auto-run when its opened.
Also, use `quit();`  as the last line, that way the instance of JMP that is opened gets closed.

Reference this link on using os: [How can I launch an instance of an application using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247724/how-can-i-launch-an-instance-of-an-application-using-python)