# How to open a csv file in Microsoft Excel in Python?

Tags: python, windows, excel, scripting, automation

```
base_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))          
_csvFilename = os.path.join(base_path, "bcForecasting.csv")
_csvFile = open (_csvFilename, 'wb')
_csvFile = csv.writer(_csvFile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

_Header = self.makeIntoList (self.root.tss.series () [0].getAllTimes (), self.originalTimesteps + _futurePeriods)
_csvFile.writerow (_Header)
```

Now I want to open the created `bcForecasting.csv` file in Excel. How to do it in Python?

Comment: I know how to open a csv file in Excel, and how to open a csv file in Python, but what does it mean to open a csv file "in Microsoft Excel in Python"?  Do you want Python to tell Excel (starting it up if it isn't running) to open the sheet?  [Aside: you didn't close the file.  It's usually a better idea to use the `with` statement.]

Comment: does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247724/how-can-i-launch-an-instance-of-an-application-using-python

Comment: Hello DSM , yes actually I "want Python to tell Excel (starting it up if it isn't running) to open the sheet". Actually I am closing the file here I have not provided the full code. Thanks

Comment: Ah, then the linked question has the answer.  The `win32com` module will work (I've used it myself to script PowerPoint.)

Comment: Hello I dont know why it is not opening for me , though I can see in the task manager that EXCEL.exe is running , also I cant delete the file as it is giving an alert "File is now available for editing"

Answer (score 8):

Usually on Windows the `.csv` filetype is configured to be opened by Excel. In this case you can just do:

```
from subprocess import Popen
p = Popen('filename.csv', shell=True)
```

In case it does not work, try pointing the full path of the Excel application:

```
subprocess.Popen(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE stack.csv')
```

Comment: Beware that opening a CSV in Excel may drop leading 0s from numeric fields like zip codes. Import with `Data > From Text` to avoid this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the 'startfile' command from the os library.

```
import os
os.startfile('filename.csv')
```

Do make sure to specify the path of the file or to set the working directory to the path where the file is located.

Comment: As the correct answer was given almost a millennia ago.. you should let the reader know which version of python you refer with your answer and why you should this method instead of the Popen variant.

Comment: @rajat is right - this has been about since Python 2.0, it uses the  Windows shell association to launch the file (has the  same effect as double-clicking the file in Windows Explorer), and avoids the overhead/ security concerns of using Popen and cmd in this way (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments )

Answer (score 0):

On a mac, use the following:

```
import os
os.system('open filename.csv')
```

Make sure to specify the path of the file or to set the working directory to the path where the file is located.