# Windows cannot find <directory> (Python)

Tags: python, windows

I need to open a file, found at *C:/Users/HP Gold/Documents/My Program/Folder/Items.csv*, in the default Windows application, which is for me, Libreoffice. I use the following command which I found on the web:

`os.system("start " + directory+"/Items.csv")`

However, I am getting an error when the line is run:
"Windows cannot find the file `"C:/Users/HP"`. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again."

What must I do because this is obviously (I think) a problem with the segment `"HP Gold"` having a space.

Comment: You probably need `"` around the directory: `os.system('start "' + directory + '/Items.csv"')`

Comment: @tgikal Thanks, that actually did work. But, now, I'm getting a blank command screen box. The title of the window is the actual directory I'm aiming for but I now have the following in the command line: C:\Users\HP Gold\Documents\My Program>. Basically, the command didn't open the file but actually just opened a cmd tab. Maybe the command isn't the one I need.

Comment: I imagine you want to open the .csv file with some program `os.startfile(directory + '/Items.csv')` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18173965/how-to-open-a-csv-file-in-microsoft-excel-in-python

Comment: Use `os.startfile`. But FYI the issue with quoting is that CMD's `start` command consumes the first quoted string as the window title, so it should be used as `start "title" "command line to run"`. The title can be an empty string.

Comment: @tgikal Thanks very much. That solution works perfectly. Eryk Sun Not sure I understand the format of what the command should be. Anyways, it works now, so nevermind. Thanks so much anyways!